# Mounting an outdoor ceiling fan in a pergola?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I'm would like to mount an outdoor fan in a pergola in an attractive way.

In the first photo I like how the junction box (?) is hidden.

[image]

Everything I can think of doing is going to end up looking like the one in this second photo.

[image]

Comment: Decorating questions are off-topic as primarily opinion-based. What's the question? If you like the first option, why aren't you doing that?

Comment: @isherwood This seems to be more of a "How do I do option 1", not "is option 1 better". (Admit that's not explicitly clear, but that's the way I read it). As such, it seems to be reasonably on topic...

Comment: Fair enough, but if the question is "How can I install a junction box through two-by lumber?" it should be revised accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I am with you, the first one is much more attractive.

The jct box must be mounted on a cross member, 2x4?, and then they added boards with a hole for the jct box.

It would be just same as if it was in ceiling and drywall except the box would need to be set at the correct depth for the thickness of the wood.

Comment: Since 2x lumber is 1-1/2" thick, you simply need to set the actual mounting board back 1-1/2" from the surface. Many boxes are, conveniently, 1-1/2" deep (deeper boxes are quite common, check yours!) so the box and lumber will match up quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but since this comes up readily in search results I wanted to share this outdoor-rated fan box I found https://www.hubbell.com/bell/en/Products/Electrical-Electronic/Boxes/Ceiling-Fan-Fixture-Support/Outdoor-Comforts-Outdoor-Ceiling-Fan-and-Luminaire-Box-White/p/3589276 which is specially designed for mounting a fan in a pergola.

Even includes a ring to ensure the top of the fan mount is covered.